# Can I use request.querystring as a SQL query's parameter in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, request.querystring

In ASP.NET I want to make a query on request.querystring but it seems not work.

```
1.var search = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["search"]);                          
2.var query= db.product2s.SqlQuery("select * from product2s where tm ='{0}'",search);
```

In the webpage I set search="F112130601" ,on the serverside I can see that value  request.querystring["search"] is  "F112130601",but the server response no record result.

However if I change the code to below line, I can get response when I view the webpage there is some record results from the server.

```
1.var search="F112130601"; 
2.var query= db.product2s.SqlQuery("select * from product2s where tm ='{0}'",search);
```

Comment: Set a break point in second line and check the value of search. Probably nothing was passed. Your code looks ok to me.

Comment: [SQL injection.. look it up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should look into prepared statements as well. There's alot of resources available if you search for it.

Comment: "afzalulh"-I have checked the value of search,it's have value "F112130601"

Comment: Can you provide the full querystring? The next suspect would be a malformed address. It needs to be something along the lines of `?search=F` or `?foo=bar&search=F`

Comment: Chris Schiffhauer--i access the server with http://serverip/home/product?search="F112130601" but get no record result from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sory.I make a mistake with my query.

the problem is i should not use "" around product code,

http://test.com/home/product?search="F112130601"

when i use below code to access the server i get record

http://test.com/home/product?search=F112130601

thanks for all of your help.